# Loosing user Interactions after moving to UIVIew to a different Subview

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app i have a main UITableView, and every cell has its own functionality.
All the cells look like a disk case, with a disk inside, and when the user clicks on the cell, the disk animates itself out of the case, and disappears.

This animation is preformed by the UITableViewCell.
To make this animation possible, i had to make the disk view, a SubView of the UITableView superclass, so the animation can continue out of the cell.

-Till here everything works perfectly!

The problem:

Every time a UITableViewCell is shown, the UITableView calls the UITableViewCells method:

```
(void)refresh{

    //Disk configuration:
    [self.diskImage setHidden:NO];
    [self addSubview:self.diskMainView];
    [self.diskMainView setFrame:originalDiskFrame];

}
```

This method is returning the "diskMainView" to the original subview (self = UITableViewCell)

After this happens, the diskMainView View, is in the right place but it receives no user interactions,
So all the buttons that are on it do not call any methods.

I don't understand what is happening here.. i'm thinking maybe once you add UIViews and UIButtons form the cell, to itself, it cannot receive user interactions...

Any suggestions would help!
Thanks!!

Comment: Instead of `self addSubview;`, what about `self.contentView addSubview:`? It's been a while since I've done something similar, but I'm pretty sure `UITableVewCell` interactions occur in its `contentView`.

Comment: Sounded like the right answer! but it didn't help.. :/